# Htaccess Redirect to home as / but keep .index.asp on directories

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need some help with an htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.asp index.php
ErrorDocument 401 http://www.domainname.com
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.domainname.com
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domainname.com
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.domainname.com
ErrorDocument 507 http://www.domainname.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domainname.com/$1 [QSA,L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index1.php?/$1 [L]
AddType text/html .html .htm .asp
AddType text/css .css
AddType image/vnd.microsoft.icon .ico
AddType image/jpeg .jpg
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 3 months"
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# compress the files
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript
# removes some bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

I have this line in my htaccess file `RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})$ /$1 [R=301,L]` at the moment it will direct any visit I receive on a index file to the root of that file so a hit on

http://www.domainname.com/index.asp will become http://www.domainname.com/ which is exactly what I want. However if the domain is hit on a subfolder with an index file it will only show the directory and not the page name as well: http://www.domainname.com/folder1/folder2/index.asp will become http://www.domainname.com/folder1/folder2/ which is not what I want.

How do I fix it so that `RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})$ /$1 [R=301,L]` will only redirect the to the root if it is hit on http://www.domainname.com/index.asp and not on all directories.

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a note, there's nothing more annoying than actually *redirecting* in case of a 404 error. If you type a URL manually and after mistyping it redirects you automatically it's super-annoying since you cannot simply correct the url you typed.

Comment: I'm curious about having both an ErrorDocument 404 and this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index1.php?/$1 [L] I think the Rewrite would take precedence.

Comment: The errordocument - does not actually work at the moment. If the page does not exists it still goes to the page. So I might comment it out late, or remove it completely.

Comment: This actually brings me to the next problem I have. If a user types in a domain like http://www.domainname.com/test it will produce a page. (even if the page does not exists), and not redirect him to a error document.

Comment: It's because of the three lines I posted about. !-f means not a file, !-d means not a directory. So what's happening is Apache checks to see if the requested file actually exists, and if it doesn't, it redirects you to the index1.php page with the name of the request pasted at the end. This does not generate a 404 code. If you want normal 404 processing, you have to remove those three lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your rewrite rule regex is matching anything up to a / (or not). We can remove that part and just have it take effect on the root directory.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})$ / [R=301,L]
```